# Is there a generic way to recursively check a deserialized object for null fields?

Tags: c#, reflection, nullreferenceexception

I receive a number of different messages that I deserialize into very dissimilar objects

Most of these objects have non-nullable fields, but across all the message types (From GraphQL, Azure service- and storage-bus, to CosmosSB and probably more that I am forgetting) some of them are happy to deserialize into objects with null fields anyway.

As such, I could very much use a component that will let me do

```
T objectFromMessage = GetObject(message);
FieldAsserter.AssertAllFieldsSet<T>(objectFromMessage); //Throws if any non-nullable fields are null
```

Do you know if any such field validation method already exists, either by default or somewhere in Nuget? Alternatively, if I have to write it myself, can you give me any clues re. where to start looking?

> What did you try and what were you expecting?

Nothing really, at this point - A cursory search of NuGet and a few thoughts about reflection is as far as I got before thinking "Maybe SO has an answer."

There are a couple of similar questions on SO already, but they appear to work for single objects - the answers are of type "write an extension method to your class that does it" but I would like a generic method that'll work for anything - I have too many message types.

Comment: What I suggest is to throw ArgumentNullException in the constructor of each model and validate the properties.

Comment: "I have too many message types" Well, that still doesbn't mean your function has to work for *any* type. You may still extract a common interface for all the common functionality. You pretty sure don't want to check for `DateTime.Now` being `null`.

Comment: Why are properties deserialized to null? Is the property optional? If so, what should the default value be?  If it is not optional it should not be null in the first place.

Comment: @RaduHatos Yes that would be my approach also in a language that allowed this but, alas, in C#, it is possible to write a deserialiser that creates an object where non-nullable properties are null, see also [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/6399) on what nullable properties "really mean"

Comment: I assume you only want to check the properties that are not nullable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, if you only want to check public properties that are NOT nullable (e.g. `string` rather than `string?`) you can filter out the nullable properties and check only the non-nullable ones like so:

**(NOTE: This requires .NET 6.0 or later.)**

```
public static void RequiresPropertiesNotNull(object item, string name)
{
    if (item is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item), "Item being checked cannot be null.");

    name ??= "<Unknown>"; // Don't want to throw if name is null, because it would hide the thing we're checking for nulls.

    var allProps = item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

    var nonNullableProps =
        from prop in allProps
        where
            prop.CanRead
         && !prop.PropertyType.IsValueType
         && !IsNullable(prop)
        select prop;

    foreach (var prop in nonNullableProps)
    {
        object? value = prop.GetValue(item);

        if (value is null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Property {prop.Name} for {name} of type {item.GetType().FullName} cannot be null.");
        
        RequiresPropertiesNotNull(value, name);
    }
}

public static bool IsNullable(PropertyInfo prop)
{
    var context = new NullabilityInfoContext();
    var info    = context.Create(prop);

    return info.WriteState is NullabilityState.Nullable;
}
```

Note that this is recursive, so it will check all the public properties and (recursively) all of their public properties and so on.

It does NOT check for self-referential objects, so if you try to use this to check an object graph that contains cycles, you WILL get a stack overflow error.

You might use it as follows: Given class `Outer` and class `Inner` where the `Inner` class contains a property `CanBeNull` which is allowed to be null and an `InnerName` property that is not allowed to be null:

```
public sealed class Outer
{
    public string OuterName { get; set; }
    public Inner  Inner     { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Inner
{
    public string  InnerName { get; set; }
    public string? CanBeNull { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the following code, the second call to `RequiresPropertiesNotNull()` will throw an exception:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var innerOk  = new Inner { InnerName = "InnerOK" };
    var innerBad = new Inner();

    var outerOk  = new Outer { OuterName = "OuterOK",  Inner = innerOk  };
    var outerBad = new Outer { OuterName = "OuterBad", Inner = innerBad };

    RequiresPropertiesNotNull(outerOk,  nameof(outerOk));  // OK
    RequiresPropertiesNotNull(outerBad, nameof(outerBad)); // Throws
}
```

If you want to remove the recursive part, just remove the line of code `RequiresPropertiesNotNull(value, name);` in the `RequiresPropertiesNotNull()` implementation.

Comment: I definitely want it recursive.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something as simple as the following? You could also add custom or default attributes to indicate a property is ignored in this check.

```
public static bool AreAllPropertiesNotNull<T>(this T obj)  where T : class
{

    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        if (property.GetCustomAttribute<IgnoreAttribute>() != null)
        {
            continue; // Skip properties with Ignore attribute
        }

        dynamic propertyValue = property.GetValue(obj);

        if (propertyValue == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Using the extension method.

```
 T objectFromMessage = GetObject(message);
 Assert.True(objectFromMessage.AreAllPropertiesNotNull());
```

Comment: "Are you looking for something as simple as the following" quite possible! I am not good at reflection, I cannot see if this does what I need without testing it, but I'll mark this as the accepted answer and go try it out. (Though I'd probably modify it with a message or an exception that says where the chain jumped off the cogs, rather than a bool)